# Pack all dependent jar along with jar creation (command line)

Tags: java, command-line, jar, executable-jar

I am trying  to create a jar using the
***"jar cfe ..."***
command.
However Iam unable to find a way to include all the dependent jar along with my build.Something like ***"Extract required libraries to generated jar"*** option in eclipse jar creation.
Please help if anyone knows how to do this in command line.

Edit:
I tried adding the jars as input-files ( docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html) but while running the jar i got ClassNotFoundException on the depended jars.
I also tried mentioning the jars in Classpath of manifest file,but that way i still have to put all the dependent jars in a file directory along with mg main jar.

Comment: If this is with plain Java command line tools (javac, jar, etc) then you must do this manually. Looking for all dependencies and specify the jars on `jar` command line. 
Or use a build tool like Ant, Maven, IDE, etc

Comment: @PeterMmm I tried adding the jars as input-files ( https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html) but that didnt work.Is there any other way to do so?(from plain java cl tools)

Comment: What not works ? `jar` gives an error message ? You cannot run `java -jar my.jar` ? You should edit your question and add the maximum of details, error messages, expected vs get results.